# Find the equation of line and finding a point in given example

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

The outer circle is $x^2+y^2=1$ and the smaller circle is $x^2+(y+1-r)^2=r^2$.

The arclength is parameterised anticlockwise with $s=0$ at the bottom as shown.

If we know $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ can we find the equation of the solid line and the point on the LHS where it intersects the smaller circle.

I would think that the point of intersection would be found after the finding the equation of the line between $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ and then substituting it into the equation for the smaller circle. Then you would take the negative $x$ solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_0$ be the point $s_0 = (0, –1)$ and $P_n$ the point on the circumference such that the minor arc $(P_n)(P_0) = s_n$. The point $P_{n+1}$ is similarly defined.

We further let the central angle subtended by the arc $(P_n)(P_0)$ be θ. Then $1.θ = s_n$, a known quantity.

Therefore, $P_n$ is located at $(–1.sin θ, –1.cos θ) = … = (–1.sin (s_n), –1.cos (s_n))$.

$P_{n+1}$ can similarly be located.

Apply two-point form to get L, the equation of the line $(P_n)(P_{n+1})$.

Solve L and C to get the required; where C is the small circle.

Note that the co-ordinates of $P_{n+1}$ = (+ve, -ve).

Comment: I dont understand your $(P_n)(P_0) = s_n$. Wouldnt it be $(P_n)(P_0) = 2\pi - s_n$.

Comment: The statement should be read as "[the length of] the minor arc $(P_n)(P_0) = s_n$".

Comment: Dont you mean the major arc?

Comment: I am counting it anticlockwisely. In any case, the arc length is a function of $s_n$. The original convention counts $s_0$ then $s_{n+1}$ and then $s_n$, which is not that natural.

Comment: Sorry the notation used is in context of a larger problem

Comment: Understood. Hope it still helps.